# Antd <Space> align items to two sides

Tags: css, antd

I want to align item A to left and item B to right using Antd  element. How to do it inline?
Currently i have:

```
<Space direction='horizontal'>
 <Space align='start'>
  <p>Item A</p>
 </Space>
 <Space align='end'>
  <p>Item B</p>
 </Space>
</Space>
```

But all items are aligned to left. How to repair it?

Comment: you can try using ```display: flex``` in the css, that would make the job pretty easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use can use the Antd Grid System to align items

```
<Row>
  <Col span={12} align="left">
    Item 1
  </Col>
  <Col span={12} align="right">
    Item 2
  </Col>
</Row>
```

[Antd grid system](https://ant.design/components/grid/#components-grid-demo-basic)